# Difference in defining Enumeration in Scala

Tags: scala, enums

In scala what is the difference in defining Enumeration as below

```
object TargetRelation extends Enumeration {
 
  val Organizations = "organizations"
  val Individuals   = "individuals"
  val Things        = "things"

}

object TargetRelation extends Enumeration {

  type TargetRelation = Value

  val Organizations = Value("organizations")
  val Individuals   = Value("individuals")
  val Things        = Value("things")

}
```

My Questions

1. Which is the preferred way of defining the Enumeration
2. What is the difference between the first and the second
3. And if i want to do a case match on a string that returns either of the above values. Which one should i use
4. What is the difference of having **type TargetRelation = Value and not having it in Enumeration**

Here is the code snippet

**Note : target.resourceType is a String**

```
target.resourceType match {
  case TargetRelationType.Individuals => {}
  case TargetRelationType.Organizationse => {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This one:

```
object TargetRelation extends Enumeration {

  type TargetRelation = Value

  val Organizations = Value("organizations")
  val Individuals   = Value("individuals")
  val Things        = Value("things")

}
```

will use build-in objects and types of `Enumeration` trait to:

- generate names for each `Value`
- assign ordering to each `Value`
- provide methods for parsing `String` into `Value`

where `TargetRelation.Value` is the actual enumeration type (which is why people sometime alias it to companion object name and import directly the alias).

This one:

```
object TargetRelation extends Enumeration {
 
  val Organizations = "organizations"
  val Individuals   = "individuals"
  val Things        = "things"

}
```

doesn't use `Value` anywhere so it is virtually the same as this one:

```
object TargetRelation {
 
  val Organizations = "organizations"
  val Individuals   = "individuals"
  val Things        = "things"
}
```

meaning - this is just namespace for constant `String`s.

However, from type safety point of view both are hardly useful as neither can be checked for exhaustiveness.

```
targetRelation match {
  case TargetRelation.Organizations => ...
  // no warning or error about which cases are missing
}
```

If you are in need of something that work like `Enum`: name parsing, automating name and ordering generation, exhaustiveness checking - both approach are **deprecated** by community which adopted `sealed trait`s with `case object`s (and [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum/)) instead:

```
// this ensured that matching is exhaustive
sealed trait TargetRelation
object TargetRelation  {

  case object Organizations extends TargetRelation
  case object Individuals extends TargetRelation
  case object Things extends TargetRelation
}
```

```
// like above but with tons of utilities
import enumeratum._

sealed trait TargetRelation extends EnumEntry
object TargetRelation extends Enum[TargetRelation] {

  case object Organizations extends TargetRelation
  case object Individuals extends TargetRelation
  case object Things extends TargetRelation

  val values = findValues
}
```

With that you can use `TargetRelation.withName("organizations")` during parsing phase (there is a support for Circe and many other libraries) and compare parsed value against case objects of a sealed hierarchy which is type safe, faster etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not an Enumeration. You could leave out extends Enumeration and achieve the same result.
It is just a singleton with a few string constants